# An empty tank that has a hole in it

Tags: calculus

> There is an empty tank that has a hole in it. Water can enter the tank at a rate of 1 gallon per second. Water leaves the tank through the hole at a rate of 1 gallon per second for each 100 gallons in the tank. How long, in seconds, will it take to fill the tank with 50 gallons of water?

---

**My approach**

Every second, 1 g enters and 1/100 g gets out. So, every second 99/100 g get in. We need to make 50 g. How many seconds?

$$ (99/100)s = 50$$

$$ s = 50*100/99 = 5000/99 $$

Do you think it is correct?

Comment: No.  There should be a big hint as to how to proceed given that you were given this question to work on in a calculus or differential equations course.  The tools and techniques you have been most recently studying will be applicable to this problem.

Comment: Can you come up with some expression for $\frac{dV}{dt}$, the rate of change of the volume of water with respect to time?  Can you then use calculus and the initial conditions (*namely that the tank starts empty*) to manipulate that earlier expression to come up with some expression for the volume in terms of time?

Comment: The rate of water leaving the tank is not constant as it depends on the amount of water in the tank.

Comment: How do you know that the rate of water leaving the tank is not constant? For me, it simply means that it leaves 1/100 of a gallon every second. This is a brain teaser that should be answered in less than 2min

Comment: Take a water bottle... poke a hole in the bottom.  The more water there is in the bottle at the moment, the more force is being exerted by the weight and pressure of the water on the top onto the water on the bottom.  The more water there is in the bottle at the moment, the more water leaves and with more force... it shoots out farther and faster.  As the amount of water in the bottle diminishes, the flow of water out of the bottom of the bottle slows down.  This is a science experiment most people see in elementary school.  Now that you are older, we can talk about equations for it.

Comment: It does not say that $\frac{1}{100}$ of a gallon leaves every second.  It says that *if* there is currently at this moment $1$ gallon of water in the bucket, then water flows out at a rate of $\frac{1}{100}$ gallons per second.  If there are $2$ gallons of water in the bucket, then water flows out at a rate of $\frac{\color{red}{2}}{100}$ gallons per second, and if 100 gallons of water currently in the bucket, it flows out at a rate of $1$ gallon per second, etc...

Comment: Now... $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is what we name the change in volume with respect to time.  This is affected by the two aspects of the problem: water flowing in at a rate of 1 gallon per second, and water flowing out at a rate of $\frac{1}{100}$ **times the current amount of water**... the correct equation is $\frac{dV}{dt}=1-\frac{1}{100}V$.  Now... continue and finish the problem with the appropriate calculus techniques.

Comment: @Marco: when there is no water, nothing comes out, the rate is zero. When there are 50 gallons, half a gallon comes out every second, when there is 100 gallons, one gallon leaves. In other word, if $V(t)$ is volume, $V(t)/100$ is the rate of water leaving the tank.

Comment: If the rate at which the water flowed out of the bucket were in fact a constant $\frac{1}{100}$ then yes, your analysis would have been correct.  You are now being asked a more challenging more age appropriate question however where we no longer consider merely the scenario where things are constant, but where things can change over time according to current conditions.  That is the whole point of a course in calculus or differential equations.

Comment: Awesome guys. Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water is entering at 1 gallon/sec , therefore ,

$${d{V_{enter}} \over dt }= 1 
  gallon/sec $$

And water leaving the tank is dependent on the volume of water present at that moment . It's rate is 1 gallon/sec for each 100 gallons . Therefore , the net leaving rate is 1 gallon \sec $\times$ $ V \over 100 $ .
Therefore ,

$${d{V_{leave}} \over dt }={ V \over 100} gallons / sec $$.
Therefore , net filing rate of water = Rate of filling - Rate of leaving .

Net filling rate = $${dV \over dt} =  { \left( 1 - {V \over 100}\right ) } gallons /sec$$.

Rearranging and integrating both sides , we get

$$\int_{0}^{50} {dV \over {1 - {V \over 100} } } = \int_{0}^{t} dt $$

We get
$$t = 100 \log {2} $$